# Converting from varchar to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server-express, numeric, varchar, alter

I have two columns `latitude` and `longitude`. I should have been set them to numeric upon importing from the fixed width file, but do not have the time to re-do that process. I'm using SQL Server Express and have to use the import wizard. There are 92 columns.

Anyways, using the following code and getting an error (shown below) when I try to change it from `varchar(9)` to `numeric (11,6)`. I have modified the settings to where I can make changes to names and datatypes. I know that using the design feature in object explorer will yield a similar error. Any other ways around this dilemma?

Code:

```
alter table dbo.tablename
    alter column latitude numeric(11,6);
```

Error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Just found the following code:

```
alter table tablename
alter column latitude float
```

Why did this work, but not the previous?

Comment: Tag your RDBMS, each one has different syntax. Are you sure all the data inside is numeric? 'if it's SQL-Server , try running: `SELECT MIN(ISNUMERIC(latitude)) FROM YourTable` . Do you get 1 or 0 ?

Comment: It returned a value of 1.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find a value.  I'm not sure is SQL Server Express supports `isnumeric()`, so this is one possibility:

```
select latitude
from tablename
where isnumeric(latitude) = 0;
```

Otherwise, you can approximate this with `like`:

```
where latitude not like '%[^0-9.]%' and
      latitude not like '%.%.%'
```